# FTP Quit Connection on an exception in Java

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client

What is the correct procedure to follow when an exception is thrown on an FTP Client in Java i.e. does the FTP session stay active or does it automatically 'quit' when an exception is thrown?

So I have this:

```
public boolean testHost(Host host, String path) {
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.setRemoteHost(host.getIpaddress());
        ftp.connect();
        ftp.login(host.getUsername(), host.getPassword());
        success = ftp.connected();

        if (success && path != null){
            ftp.chdir(path);
        }           
        ftp.quit();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        LOG.info("Host IPAddress cannot be reached on " + host.getIpaddress());
        success = false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        success = false;
    } catch (FTPException e) {
        success = false;
    }
    return success;  
}
```

The quit command doesnt get hit when any of the exceptions get called - is this a problem? Could there potentially be 100's of active connections open to the FTP Client if this method keeps getting hit? Or am I worrying about nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Move your ftp.quit() statement so it is just above the return statement

Like this:

```
public boolean testHost(Host host, String path) {
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.setRemoteHost(host.getIpaddress());
        ftp.connect();
        ftp.login(host.getUsername(), host.getPassword());
        success = ftp.connected();

        if (success && path != null){
            ftp.chdir(path);
        }           
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        LOG.info("Host IPAddress cannot be reached on " + host.getIpaddress());
        success = false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        success = false;
    } catch (FTPException e) {
        success = false;
    }
    ftp.quit();
    return success;  
}
```

Since none of your catches terminate the method, execution will continue to the ftp.quit() statement and finally return with the success result.

Optionally, you can use the finally clause at the end of the try and put the ftp.quit() statement in that.

AFAIK the choice is preferential.